# NonUniqueObjectException where the session does not contain the object itself?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have this very simple method:

```
public D saveDocument(D document) {
    final Session currentSession = getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println("Current session contains document: " + currentSession.contains(document));
    try {
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(document);
    } catch (NonUniqueObjectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return document;
}
```

and this is what the second statement and the stacktrace prints for me:

> Current session contains document: false
>   org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session:
>   [com.innflow.ebtam.model.document.flowexpense.ExpenseDocument#6813]

This happens when I am trying to save document with id 6813. So Hibernate initially tells me the object is *not* in the session, but then when I try to call [Session#saveOrUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)) I am getting the `NonUniqueObjectException`.

What is it that I am missing here? What may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that `document` you are trying to save is detached. That is why the `contains` method results in a false, even though an entity with the same id is already in the session.

Once the persistence provider tries to attach and save the entity, it checks that there is already an entity with that id in the current session.

You should try to `merge` instead of `save` in that case:

```
currentSession.merge(document);
```

Comment: This is so confusing.. I still do not understand how contains returns false but then as you said " it checks that there is already an entity with that id in the current session"

Comment: I am sure that after you perform merge.. then return entity would result in true when passed to contains. Its not about same id.. its about the object being managed by the persistence provider (proxied).